# Setting Pino level gives me 'log_1.default.level is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, pinojs

I have set up a log utility module using Pino in a KeystoneJS/NodeJS project.  It works fine, but I want to limit the log level when it goes into production.

The utility file, `util/log.js` is set up

```
import pino from 'pino';

const logger = pino({
    prettyPrint: { colorize: true }
});

export default logger;
```

and imported into files (such as here `index.ts`)

`import log from './util/log';`

but when I try to set the level (here I set it to 'development', to test that this works, later it will be 'production')

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') log.level('error');`

I get the following error

```
TypeError: log_1.default.level is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/yaa-cms-new/tsout/index.js:29:19)
```

However all calls to `log.error` or `log.info` work normally throughout the application, that is, it's importing Pino correctly and I can use it.  I just can't set the level.  When I trace out the imported `log` object I get

```
[1589881349511] INFO  (18641 on AGOMA1002.local):
    levels: {
      "labels": {
        "10": "trace",
        "20": "debug",
        "30": "info",
        "40": "warn",
        "50": "error",
        "60": "fatal"
      },
      "values": {
        "trace": 10,
        "debug": 20,
        "info": 30,
        "warn": 40,
        "error": 50,
        "fatal": 60
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong -- any clues much appreciated!

Using Node 12.14.0, the latest TypeScript and

```
    "pino": "^6.2.1",
    "pino-pretty": "^4.0.0"
```

Comment: `log.level = 'error'` should fix it

Answer (score 3):

As @Manuel Spigolon correctly points out above, the correct way to set the Pino level is

`log.level = 'error'`

because `logger.level` is a getter/setter (see https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=loggerlevel-string-gettersetter), which I knew, but which I somehow failed to process.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
log.level = 'trace'
```

or use environment variables:

```
const logger = require('pino')({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
    prettyPrint: true
 });
```